# Get all the files changed by me in one branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have started a branch from a development branch long ago.
Now after many months of making my changes and merging development into it, I can't find changes originally done by me in that very branch.

When I look through the history of that branch using Visual Studio, I see so many commits and it's hard, or impossible, for me to spot the changes that I have done while working on that branch (which files, what changes).

I need it because recently my colleague merged that branch into development back and then undone that (because of some problems).
I don't know exactly how he did it, but I don't see my changes in that branch anymore, but the whole branch history is still there.

Answer (score 1):

**See all commits by a given author excluding merge commits**

```
git log --author="Bento" --no-merges
```

**See more options to modify the log output**

```
git help log
```

Comment: With this command I get also merge commits. I need commits where I chaged files in that branch..